# Заполнить масив обьектов из файла

Tags: c++, ооп, объекты

Задача
Нужно чтобы был в файлике был список студентов и производить с ними операции добавлять студентов удалять и тп. Не знаю как лучше сделать есть класс Student и класс Group

```
class Student
{
private:
    int id;
    string name;
    string surname;
    int kont_or_budzh;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,const Student& student);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is,Student& student);
public:
    Student();
    Student(int,string,string,int);
    void setStd(int,string,string,int);
    void print();
    int getId();
    string getName();
    string getSurName();
    ~Student();
};
```

//класс Group

```
class Group
{
private:
    Student s[20];
    string nameGrp;
    int count;
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& os,const Group& group);
    friend istream& operator >>(ostream& os,const Group& group);
public:
    Group();
    Group(string);
    void set(string);
    void print();
    void AddStudent();
    ~Group();
 };
```

В классе Group я использую массив элементов Student не знаю правильно это или нет как лучше реализовать данную задачу ?

Comment: Лучше вектор - вы же заранее не знаете, сколько студентов будет в группе...

Comment: а ещё лучше вектор/список указателей на студентов... иначе при роспуске группы придётся убивать всех, а это несколько жестоко...